# c++11 : generic type push via a std::function<T(const U&)>

Tags: c++, c++11, notify, generic-programming

I am trying to build a generic push component.

I have a class `store<T>` which

- has a T t; member
- has a `void push(const T & t)` method called by data providers.

When push is called by a provider, I want a value computed by a `std::function< T2(const T&)>`  and all clients (`store<T2>`) are notified
with that result value of type T2. A store client has first to subscribe to store via a `linker<T, T2>` object.

```
template <class data> class store
{
    data data_;
    std::list< action<data > > m_links;
public:
    void push(const data & e)
    {
        data_ = e;
        for(action<data> a : m_links)
            a(data_);
    }

    void subscribe(action<data> d)
    {
        m_links.push_back(d);
    }
};
```

Linker object :

```
template < class data1, class data2 > class linker
{
    // source where come the push calls
    store<data1> & m_source;
    // targets to be notified after computation
    std::list<store<data2> * > m_targets;
    // computation function
    std::function< data2(const data1 &)> m_func;

public:
    linker(store<data1> & source, std::function< data2(const data1 &)> func)
    : m_source(source), m_func(func)
    {
        m_source.subscribe([this](const data1 & d){this->push(d);});
    }
    // add a client
    void add_target(store<data2> & target)
    {
        m_targets.push_back(&target);
    }
    void push(const data1 & e)
    {
        //compute result
        data2 d2 = m_func(e);
        // notify all
        for(store<data2> * s2 : m_targets)
        {
            s2->push(d2);
        }
    }
};
```

Use case :

```
int main()
{
    // function : just increment an int, return as double
    std::function<double(const int &) > f_inc = [](const int& i){ return i+1;};
    // function : display the data 
    std::function<int(const double&) > f_display = [](const double& d){ std::cout << "value=" << d << std::endl ; return 0;};

    store<int> source;
    store<double> target, target2;

    linker<int, double> l(source, f_inc);
    l.add_target(target);
    l.add_target(target2);


    linker<double, int> display(target, f_display);

    source.push(1);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to suppress the explicit-ness of the 'linker' object. I did not succeed because I dont know how to handle the fact that when a store client subscribes to a store object, the object can not store a pointeur to store since it does not know the type T2 !

I would like to write something like that:

```
std::function<double(const int &) > f_inc = [](const int& i){ return i+1;};
store<int> source;
store<double> target;

source.link_to(target, f_inc);
```

and be able to unsubscribe :

```
source.unlink(target, f_inc);
```

or with ids:

```
id i = source.link_to(target, f_inc);
source.unsubscribe(i);
```

I am using codeblocks + mingw 4.8.1 under windows xp.
I guess a design pattern exists for this use case ...

ps: I cant use boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that by *explicitness* you mean the fact that `Linker` has template parameters.

I would envision something like:

```
class Broker {
public:
    Broker(): _lastId(0) {}

    //
    // Notification
    //
    template <typename T>
    void notify(store<T> const& source, T const& event) {
        auto const it = _sources.find(&source);

        if (it == _sources.end()) { return; }

        for (size_t id: it->second) { _targets.find(id)->second->invoke(&event); }
    } // notify

    //
    // Subscription
    //
    template <typename T, typename U>
    size_t subscribe(Store<T> const& source, U&& callback) {
        _targets[++_lastId] = std::unique_ptr<Action>(new ActionT<T>(callback));

        _sources[&source].insert(_lastId);

        return _lastId;
    } // subscribe

    template <typename T, typename U>
    size_t subscribe(Store<T> const& source, U const& callback) {
        return this->subscribe(source, U{callback});
    } // subscribe

    void unsubscribe(size_t id) {
        auto const it = _targets.find(id);

        if (it == _targets.end()) { return; }

        void const* source = it->second->_source;

        auto const it2 = _sources.find(source);
        assert(it != _sources.end());

        it2->second.erase(id);

        if (it2->second.empty()) { _sources.erase(it2); }

        _targets.erase(it);
    } // unsubscribe

    template <typename T>
    void unsubscribe(store<T> const& source) {
        auto const it = _sources.find(&source);

        if (it == _sources.end()) { return; }

        for (size_t id: it->second) { _targets.erase(id); }

        _sources.erase(it);
    } // unsubscribe

private:
    //
    // Action/ActionT<T> perform Type Erasure (here, we erase T)
    //
    struct Action {
        Action(void const* source): _source(source) {}

        virtual void invoke(void const*) = 0;

        void const* _source;
    }; // struct Action

    template <typename T>
    class ActionT: Action {
    public:
        ActionT(store<T> const& source, std::function<void(T)> f):
             Action(&source),
             _callback(std::move(f))
        {}

        virtual void invoke(void const* event) {
           _callback(T(*static_cast<T const*>(event));
        }

    private:
        std::function<void(T)> _callback;
    }; // class ActionT

    using Targets = std::map<size_t, std::unique_ptr<Action>>;
    using Sources = std::map<void const*, std::set<size_t>>;

    size_t _lastId;
    Targets _targets;
    Sources _sources;
}; // class Broker
```

As you may see, fairly complicated... and the worst of it ? It is still unsafe. Specifically, there are lifetime issues:

- if you register a callback that has references to the external world, you must remove it before those references die
- it would be cleaner to remove the sources when they disappear (to prevent a leak)

There are some ways to work around it, you might want to look into [signal/slots](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals.html) which help implementing this logic without tying it to a specific object.

Comment: "explicitness" means I dont want an explicit 'linker' role object but I want it stored (at least masked) inside the source `store<T>` object. I am testing your proposition right now (and thanks for your interest btw).

Comment: @norisknofun: Ah I see, well the idea of a `broker` is completely off then :) In this case, I recommend having a look at signal/slots since those are exactly about "decentralized" communication network between objects.